# Scrambling strings with random.shuffle in Python 3.x

Tags: python, algorithm, function, python-3.x, recursion

Hello I'm new to programming and have been teaching myself Python through various means for the past year.I have been lurking here for a while and have gotten a lot of help but now i have a specific problem:

Im working on a word scramble game and i ran into a snag.

Python 3.x code

```
def scrambler(word):
    word_to_scramble = list(word)
    random.shuffle(word_to_scramble)
    new_word = ''.join(word_to_scramble)
    return new_word
```

Now the code above works as desired, but occasionally it will return the original word i fed into the scrambler function.

My question is: Is there a way to ensure that the string returned is always different than the one given. 
I attempted to use the scrambler function inside itself with a while loop, which would crash the script and give me an error stating the recursion limit had been reached.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hitting the recursion limit, then it's likely that you're trying to scramble a 1-character word.  However, it's quite easy to remove the recursion in this problem ...:

```
def _scrambler(word):
    word_to_scramble = list(word)
    random.shuffle(word_to_scramble)
    new_word = ''.join(word_to_scramble)
    return new_word

def scrambler(word):
   new_word = _scrambler(word)
   while new_word == word and len(word) > 1:
       new_word = _scrambler(word)
   return new_word
```

I've added a `len(word) > 1` check so this should eventually give you a different word than what you put in if it is possible to do so.

Comment: Probably want to fix the typo you copied / pasted from OP.  `''.join()` instead of `''join.()`

Answer (score 0):

hope you enjoy with programming Chris.
well if u test like this...

```
 from random import shuffle
 word='test'
 def scrambler(word):
      word_to_scramble = list(word)
      shuffle(word_to_scramble)
      new_word = ''.join(word_to_scramble)
      return new_word
 print(scrambler(word))
```

u will get the word test in ~ <25th try as i did ...(cant be sure because its not realy random)

so u can just put some if statement in your function. and if new_world is same as word u can just recall the function again... and it doesn't need any loop. its like some recursive base function.

something like this...

```
enter code here

from random import shuffle
word = 'test'
def scrambler(word):
    word_to_scramble = list(word)
    shuffle(word_to_scramble)
    new_word = ''.join(word_to_scramble)
    #print (new_word) if u want to check what is going on ...
    if new_word == word:
         scrambler(word) 
    elif new_word != word:
         return new_word  
         print(new_word)
scrambler(word)
```